# Starring messages bug

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

When starring messages at the side, the actual message does not star:

[image]
We can see that the message by jadarnel27 is starred at the side but not the actual message itself.
(Don't suspend GnomeSlice, its a joke)

Comment: you can close your own questions as dupe with one vote, by clicking the "I agree" button in the banner on top instead of casting actual close vote. Oh wait.. you did. Both close vote and this. LOL

Comment: I'm weird. So are mods. They post comments as answers. Let me find it...